I now have to press the Fn button to get normal F key operation. How do I change it back?
I randomly pressed some keys while playing solitare and now the normal F key operations require me to hold down the Fn key.
For example, I have always been able to press F3 to raise the volume. Now when I press F3 the search bar drops down. If I hold down the Fn button and press F3 the volume will raise...
How do I change it back?

The function keys on your keyboard have switched to their secondary functions. To switch them back to their primary functions (where you don't need to hold down the Fn key), you'll need to find the "Fn Lock" or "Function Lock" key on your keyboard. This key is often labeled with "Fn" and a lock icon.
Here's how to switch back to the primary function keys:
Locate the "Fn Lock" or "Function Lock" key on your keyboard. It's usually found in the top row of keys, near the F1-F12 keys.
Press and hold the "Fn" key.
While holding the "Fn" key, press the "Fn Lock" or "Function Lock" key.
Release both keys.
